# Two Operating System On Two Different Hard Drives

Tags: boot, windows, hard-drive

I have installed two different Hard drives on a single computer where HDD-1(make:SATA) has windows on it and HDD-2(make: Western-Digital) has Linux on it.
At Boot-up I am not getting the option of selecting between the two HDD rather it's selecting windows as default. I am totally unable to select HDD-1.

What is the way to do that?

Comment: Two Os's you have installed in different hdds. So you have to go to boot option at POST and choose HDD1 or HDD2. If you want Ubuntu as default OS.. You have to choose it in Boot priority accordingly. BIOS settings will workout it.

Comment: BIOS (or eufi) chooses which boots first; and if non-gpt which MBR (first sector of hdd) is loaded. Commonly this is a boot-loader (like `grub`) that can ask which you want to load. There are lots of boot-loaders, grub being the default for Ubuntu but other options can be used, let alone windows has its own too (though seldom used).  When you install Ubuntu, you are asked which disk to install it on, it should match the setting of your BIOS.  (it can be re-installed if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You'll not get option in OS to select which OS boot first.

 only from boot menu from bios setup or from fast boot menu. You can select default HDD or select which HDD will start its OS.